# Make Buffer emit values before specified timestamp?

Tags: android, rx-java

I have logic for 3 button clicks and I want to add one more action on first and second clicks immediately without waiting for ending of specified timestamp. (Click 1 -> New logic -> Click 2 -> New Logic -> Click 3 -> Old Logic and repeat every 3 seconds)
Can I do it with RxJava buffer? Otherwise what should I use in RxJava?

I've written code below and it's working fine, but my new logic executing only after waiting 3 seconds, can I make it execute immediately?

```
RxView.clicks(textField)
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .buffer(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS, 3)
                .filter(click -> (click.size() >= 1 && click.size() <= 3))
                .subscribe(this::someFunc,
                        Throwable::printStackTrace);
```

```
private void someFunc(@NonNull List<Unit> list) {
        if (list.size() == 3) {
            Log.d("TAG", "if");
        } else if (list.size() >= 1 && list.size() < 3) {
            Log.d("TAG", "else if");
        }
    }
```

I want to achieve a logic like clicking on build number in android settings to become a developer, but in my case on 3 clicks should show "you are upgraded" message, on 1 click "press 2 more times", on 2 clicks "press 1 more time".